# File Manager For asp.net CKEditor

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor

Is There any fileManager for [asp.net CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/download) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't mind paying for one, there is http://ckfinder.com/

I've rolled my own for the previous FCK editor, which is also a good option. It's not difficult to implement.

I did a quick search - there are likely open source / free alternatives as well. Found http://www.dzone.com/links/an_open_file_manager_for_ckeditor_30.html - but I don't know anything about it.

Comment: As an aside, I bought this for a classic asp site. We had a few issues, but the support was fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

There is a file manager built into CKEditor. If you open up the links, images, flash etc options you should see a "Browse Server" option which opens the file manager.

Comment: I think you're thinking of the previous FCK editor.

Comment: Yeah you're corrent Scott sorry about that. I was looking at an instance of CKEditor with CKFinder built in and forgot we had to buy it.